# why does php stat every single timezone file?

Tags: php, apache, debugging, stat, strace

At the top of my configuration file, I have this:

```
[PHP]
date.timezone="America/Toronto"
```

When I execute my code which makes no reference to time-related functions (except when I use the `date()`, `strtotime()` and `time()` functions), I get the following kind of output when running a trace:

```
stat("/usr/share/zoneinfo/(insert continent name here)/(insert state here)/(insert city here)", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1677, ...}) = 0
```

Except there are at least a few hundred of these calls. They don't show up all the time, but when I restarted apache and ran the exact same PHP script on the server, the calls appear.

What would cause PHP to stat every single zone information file before running the rest of the normal program code?

Comment: Which PHP modules have you installed?